# Angular 6 - get csv response from httpClient

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, http

Can any one please give an example of fetching application/octet-stream response from angular 6 httpClient. I am using the below code and it doesn't work ( I get unknown error - 401 response) -

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

getJobOutput() {
    this.workflowService.fetchOutput(this.jobId,this.outputId).subscribe((response : any) => { // download file
              var blob = new Blob([response.blob()], {type: 'application/octet-stream'});
    var filename = 'file.csv';
    saveAs(blob, filename);
    });
   }
```

Service is as below -

```
 fetchOutput(jobId : string, outputId) {
    var jobOutputURL = "myEnpoint";
     var params = this.createHttpAuthorization(jobOutputURL,"GET");
     params["format"] = "csv";
    const options = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders( { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                                        'Accept' : 'application/octet-stream',
                                        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'}
                                    )};

    var endpoint = `${jobOutputURL}?oauth_consumer_key=${params["oauth_consumer_key"]}&oauth_signature_method=${params["oauth_signature_method"]}&oauth_nonce=${params["oauth_nonce"]}&oauth_timestamp=${params["oauth_timestamp"]}&oauth_version=1.0&format=${params["format"]}&oauth_signature=${params["oauth_signature"]}`;
return this.httpClient.get(endpoint, {...options, responseType: 'blob'});
  }
```

Comment: Your request looks fine, if you are getting `401` the you are not authorized to download the the `.csv`. Check your API, is your access allowed.

Comment: 401 error means "Unauthorized". Are you sure you authorized the request?

Comment: Yes, it is. The same request when asked in jquery works fine.

Comment: This request works -  this.getOutputFileURL = function(jobId, outputId, format) {
        var type = "GET",
            url = this.apiLocation + "/jobs/" + jobId + "/output/" + outputId + "/",
            params = buildOauthParams(this.apiKey);
        $.extend(params, {format: format || "Raw"});
        var signature = generateSignature(type, url, params, this.apiSecret);
        $.extend(params, {oauth_signature: signature});
        window.location.assign(url + "?" + $.param(params));
    };

Answer (score 8):

To fetch an application/octet-stream, you have to set `arraybuffer` as the response type in the Angular `HttpHeaders`.

This is the service method:

```
fetchOutput(): Observable<ArrayBuffer> {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();

    const options: {
        headers?: HttpHeaders;
        observe?: 'body';
        params?: HttpParams;
        reportProgress?: boolean;
        responseType: 'arraybuffer';
        withCredentials?: boolean;
    } = {
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    };

    return this.httpClient
        .get('https://your-service-url.com/api/v1/your-resource', options)
        .pipe(
            map((file: ArrayBuffer) => {
                return file;
            })
        );
}
```

This is the call to the service method and  to the `saveAs` function:

```
this.yourService
    .fetchOutput()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
        const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
        const fileName = 'Your File Name.csv';
        saveAs(blob, fileName);
    })
```

As other users are suggestion: 401 Unauthorized is usually a client side error due to missing credentials.

Comment: Hi Julien,Thank you for the code above. I still a  GET request with 401 (Unauthorized) error. However, the same URL when I paste on postman, gives me the correct response. I doubt this is authorization issue as I am able to access other types of API's that are hosted on the same server.

Comment: Do you use windows authentication, or what kind of authorization? Tools like postman can implicitly set authorization, whilst Angular cannot.

Comment: I am using oauth 1.0 and setting these params - oauth_consumer_key, 
oauth_signature_method: HMAC-SHA1
oauth_nonce, 
oauth_timestamp, 
oauth_version: 1.0
Also, other GET requests work with these oauth 1.0 parameters (via my angular 6 application).
oauth_signature: VTat UuyYG5bWrpSZ18lJfFeUjQ=

Comment: Try one of the following: Compare the url that Angular produces via the chrome developer network tab with the one that postman creates. Double check the headers, that Angular sets, and compare them with the one postman creates. Try debugging the authorization method in your backend to check, whether the pararams, that you define in Angular, reach your endpoint correctly.

Comment: Thanks Julien. Since, I have another application which runs successfully in Jquery as well, I see two differences - in jquery, request header has Host in request header as "server domain" , whereas my angular application has origin in request header as "http://localhost:4200". Do you know if this would make a difference?

Comment: According to the OAuth 1.0 spec, it should not make a difference. There is a list of possible errors for the 401 code on the oauth page in chapter 10 (https://oauth.net/core/1.0/): Invalid Consumer Key, Invalid / expired Token, Invalid signature or Invalid / used nonce

Comment: Thanks Julien. But I know for sure that expired token is not the issue as I have worked with the token/invalid signatures issues earlier.

Comment: What is the `pipe(map(...)` for? It seems to work without this extra step.

Comment: @Aetherix Yes, in the above case the map operator is not required, though I added it to indicate, that you could alter the output of the observable

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
this.httpClient.get(endpoint, {...options, responseType: 'text'}).subscribe((data: any) => {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = "data:text/csv," + data;
    let filename = "CSVDownload";
    a.setAttribute("download", filename + ".csv");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a);
},
(error) => {
    console.log('error', error);
});
```